# OS X: (Vector) Drawing App with Smoothing

Tags: osx, drawing, vector-graphics

When I first experienced Flash (when it was still Macromedia!) I was impressed that its (vector) drawing tool included smoothing. This gave all drawings a nice sketched appearance, and could turn my poor scrawls into something that looked deliberate and professional.

Is there an app available which will similarly smooth out hand drawings, but still maintain a vector drawing format?

Preferably the app will at least export to SVG. For my own preferences I would also like one on the App Store, with a trial version available.

Thanks